# How to look back at previous record of same type

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to look back at the previous matching record to work out the time difference between it at the current record.

The context is that users on our system are able to perform certain actions that are considered valuable to us. We want to reward users who perform these actions, however there’s a cool-down period between giving out these rewards.

Every unique action is eligible for a reward if it is either the first time it has happened or at least 1 hour has passed since the last action of the same type by that user.

The activity table looks like this:

```
user_id, action_id, timestamp
1, 1, 2019-01-01 13:00:00
1, 1, 2019-01-01 13:30:00
1, 1, 2019-01-01 14:30:00
2, 1, 2019-01-01 14:35:00
2, 2, 2019-01-01 14:36:00
2, 2, 2019-01-01 15:50:00
```

and I would like to create a view to achieve the following

```
user_id, action_id, timestamp, eligible
1, 1, 2019-01-01 13:00:00, true
1, 1, 2019-01-01 13:30:00, false
1, 1, 2019-01-01 14:30:00, true
2, 1, 2019-01-01 14:35:00, true
2, 2, 2019-01-01 14:36:00, true
2, 2, 2019-01-01 15:50:00, true
```

I have tried to do this with a CTE as I feel that's the most correct but I haven’t been able to figure out the how to look back at the previous record of the same action type by the same user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the LAG window function to look back at the previous row by that user and action.

```
SELECT user_id, 
       action_id, 
       timestamp, 
       CASE WHEN COALESCE(timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1) 
                  OVER (partition by user_id, action_id),
                  '1 hour'::interval) >= '1 hour'::interval 
         THEN true 
         ELSE false
       END 
FROM activity;
```

The coalesce is just there because if it's the first time the user has performed that action timestamp - lag(timestamp, 1) OVER ... will return null.